# Cuando hago una consulta dentro de una funcion para asignar el resultado a una variable, ¿Si el query no devuelve nada, guarda un valor nulo?

Tags: postgresql, sql, variables

```
SELECT c.horas_aportadas
INTO horas_aportadas_coordinador
FROM voluntario c
WHERE new.id_coordinador = c.nro_voluntario;
```

En ese codigo, el `id_coordinador` es un atributo que puede ser nulo, por lo que si lo es entonces la consulta no devuelve nada, y lo que quiero saber es que se guarda en la variable `horas_aportadas_coordinador`.
¿Se guarda un valor nulo, o se queda con el valor que yo le asigne por defecto cuando la cree(Cuando cree la variable le asigne un -1)?

Comment: No va a guardar nada porque en la tabla voluntario, el nro_voluntario es primary key(supongo) por lo tanto no puede ser nulo y la condicion WHERE no se cumplira debido a que no tienes guardado un campo -1 ni mucho menos nulo en el campo nro_voluntario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aunque hayas asignado algo a la variable; si luego ejecutas una consulta que no trae resultados, quedara en ella el valor nulo, sobreescribiendo el valor preexistente.
una solucion seria usar ISNULL o lo que tu RDBMS soporte para en caso que sea nulo el resultado, mantenga el valor anterior)